# Problem with postgres using Rails API / Rspec / Postgresql problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rspec-rails

I have problem during running test via rspec

```
bundle exec rspec spec/requests/authentication_spec.rb

An error occurred while loading ./spec/requests/authentication_spec.rb.
Failure/Error: ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError:
  FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "test"
```

My development db is working ok, I tried put data to db and succeed.
I found many many solutions, but nothing works.
my db config:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: test
  adapter: postgresql
  host: localhost
  port: 5432
  user: test
  password: test

test:
  <<: *default
  database: test
  port: 5432
  user: test
  password: test

production:
  <<: *default
  url: <%= ENV['MY_APP_DATABASE_URL'] %>
```

What I am missing? I am new in postgresql and I want to learn rails, but I stucked on postgres (I need some basic knowledge about  postgres too)

I am using ubuntu 20, ruby '2.7.0', rails 6.1.3.2, rspec-rails 5.0.1, postgres (PostgreSQL) 13.3 (Ubuntu 13.3-1.pgdg20.04+1)

Comment: Try bin/rails db:test:prepare

Comment: Oh no wait, sry. Do not use the same dB for both development and tests. Name one app_development and the other app_test. Then run bin/rails db:setup.

Answer (score 0):

There are two cases.

1. Database name should be different to have separate database for Development and test.
2. Need to add host key in test environment.

When we include default in any environment, we don't need to repeat same information mentioned again in that environment.

Ex.

```rb
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  host: localhost

development:
  <<: *default
  database: app_dev
  port: 5432
  user: test
  password: test

test:
  <<: *default
  database: app_test
  port: 5432
  user: test
  password: test

production:
  <<: *default
  url: <%= ENV['MY_APP_DATABASE_URL'] %>
```

Also make sure that the user name and password of database match.
So if your development environment is working fine we just need to check `host` and different database.

But if your development environment also having same issue(I mean when you start `rails s` and load the page in browser and it's not working and showing DB connection error instead) then you need to verify your database user and password.

Let me know if anything doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Thank you, now I can easily drink my whisky during the son birthday party and I do not have to think about it. I was sure I set localhost by default, but seems there was not only problem, now I can see that was the problem. Also I had to run `rails db:environment:set RAILS_ENV=test` and it works.

Comment: @AndrzejOlearka So was my answer useful?